# Only part of the element responding to browser window resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a gallery but seems like every time I resize the browser window, some part(gallery info div) does not respond to the resize immediately, I need to hover the cursor on it to make it refresh and move to where it should be. Anyone has similar experience?

website:[www.test.com](http://www.ruoxicui.com/user.html)

image link:
http://i405.photobucket.com/albums/pp133/trancisky/ScreenShot2014-06-14at91954PM.png

My html for each tile:

```
  <div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="section first">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="portfolio-grid portfolioContainer ">
       <ul id="thumbs" class="col3"><li class="item">
      <div class="portfolio-image-wrapper">
      <img src="assets/img/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="edit-menu">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Rename</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Delete</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item-info-overlay">
        <a class="hideModelLink" href="#">ModelLink</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-info">
      <h4 class="text-dark no-margin title semi-bold"><a class="" target="_blank" href="#">Mobile App</a></h4>
      <p>4/15/2014</p>
    </div>
    <a class="edit-button"></a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </li>
```

My css for 'item-info'(the div that fails to respond to the resize):

```
.item-info {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 10px 17px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
.item-info h4.title{ 
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -moz-binding: url('assets/xml/ellipsis.xml#ellipsis');
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where are the normal bootstrap classes here which dictate what should happen at each site? i.e `col-md-12` etc? This is just CSS, including bootstrap doesn't make magic happen - You have to wave your wand first ...

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide more details on your implementation, or a JSFiddle/live demo exhibiting the problem? None of the code you provided exhibits any degree of responsiveness, making it difficult to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Sorry that my question was not clear enough. I update the html a little bit. And you can also find my actual test website at: [link](http://www.ruoxicui.com/user.html).  Thanks!!

Comment: I'm still fail to see how that site is responsive. Those boxes aren't moving using bootstrap, it's a different plugin.

Comment: Thank you!I will try to better frame my question and see if there are more detail I can find regarding this issue.